# Add ShaderImageView programmatically

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'd like you run this lines of code

```
ShaderImageView imageview = new ShapeImageView(getBaseContext(), null, R.style.hexagonstyle);  
newphoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.image08);  
layout.addView(newphoto);
```

and get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No resource is defined as shape
```

*hexagone* is defined as

```
<style name="hexagonstyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="siBorderColor">@color/hexagoninnerborder</item>
    <item name="siBorderWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="siShape">@raw/maskcopya</item>
</style>
```

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.2@aar'
}
```

For more info about ShapeImageView: https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

How can I add a *ShapeImageView* programmatically? Maybe the params of  *ShapeImageView()* are wrong ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way round:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.contactlist, null);
ImageView contactimage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactimage);
```

I put *ShaderImageView* into *contactlist.xml* and style it there

*solved* :)